# Can I delete Ktorrent *.dnd files?

Tags: kde, bittorrent, ktorrent

I've noticed that *.dnd files in ~/.kde/share/apps/ktorrent consumed 8 Gb of disk space.

As I understand, dnd means "do not download" -> just temp files? Wouldn't Ktorrent recreate/redownload it after deletion?

Is it safe to delete these files? Won't it affect my active torrents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally deleted it -> my 800 active torrents gone ^_^

Answer: don't delete *.dnd files if you don't want all your torrents to be deleted

Answer (score -1):

From my simple understanding :

Torrent clients download pieces of data , maybe this piece for a file or another file or maybe it's the end of a file and the start of another one , or it's required to check the healthy of files

I used to use utorrent in the past/$windows$ and they end with .bat so i delete them after download and seeding a little . Although , I don't use ktorrent but I suppose the all follow the same principle

Read this from [Bittorrent faq](http://www.bittorrent.com/help/manual/faq05#Why_does_uTorrent_create_or_download_parts_of_files_I_set_to_Dont_Download)

```
Why does BitTorrent create or download parts of files I set to "Don't Download?"
This occurs because BitTorrent has no concept of files, only pieces. Because
multiple files can share the same piece, and BitTorrent has to download an entire
piece to check its hash, it will effectively download data for another file
(regardless of whether it was skipped). There is nothing you can do about
BitTorrent downloading data for another file if the data is a part of a piece that also 
belongs to another file that you do want downloaded
```